# Flutter app throwing error while calling configure method of Amplify on application resume in android device

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, flutter-plugin, flutteramplify, amplify-flutter

In my flutter project, I'm using the AWS Amplify storage plugin to upload files.

For that, I have added below dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  amplify_storage_s3: <1.0.0
  amplify_flutter: <1.0.0
  amplify_auth_cognito: <1.0.0
```

And in main.dart file added one function to configure Amplify

```
  void configureAmplify() async {
    // First add plugins (Amplify native requirements)
    AmplifyStorageS3 storage = new AmplifyStorageS3();
    AmplifyAuthCognito auth = new AmplifyAuthCognito();
    Amplify.addPlugins([auth, storage]);

    // Configure
    await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig('cashify-bazaar'));
  }
```

I call this `configure` method on button click and it works fine.

But the problem is that once I called the `configure` method and put an application in the background by the back press, and then resume from recent apps on android device, It throws an error

> W/GeneratedPluginsRegister(21233): Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@99d4e49) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.

and does not call onAttachedToEngine of flutter plugin, and because of this no plugin channel is registered which cause an error

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException( No implementation found for method <method_name> on channel <channel_name>

why the `onAttachedToEngine` method of FlutterPlugin is not called, once I have called `Amplify.configure`?

Answer (score 2):

This is the same issue as https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/99 which is fixed by https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/pull/345

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the merged master code of amplify-flutter is not published yet, so if I add amplify-flutter dependency as a Git dependency it failed to resolve project `:amplify_flutter`.